# c++ call to the c function mbstowcs() changes a paramater

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have a mbstowcs() that doesn't work well:

```
mbstowcs(pParams->strDstFile, parParams->DstFile, sizeof(parParams->DstFile));
```

the arguments' values at debug are :

```
pParams->strDstFile = 0x0018e70c
parParams->DstFile = 121 long null terminated string.
sizeof(parParams->DstFile) = 1024
```

the arguments types are:

```
TCHAR strDstFile[2048]; 
char DstFile[1024];
```

after a single step in into mbstowcs( wchar_t  *pwcs, const char *s, size_t n):

```
wchar_t  *pwcs = 0x0018ef0c
```

which is a different value than the one was sent. this causes the above call to malfunction.

p.s. in another function call , almost the same as this one, with the only difference of a different first argument (pwcs) , there is no problem.

Consecutive runs of the app gives the same results, with the exact same address values.

while looking at another post, it seems like a dangling pointer/ buffer overflow, though I can't track it with a memory breakpoint.

I'm thinking maybe stack corruption?

thanks all.

Comment: Just for grins (for purposes of debugging), try this: `mbstowcs(&(pParams->strDstFile[0]), &(parParams->DstFile[0]), sizeof(parParams->DstFile));`

Comment: You are using a TCHAR data type which is a macro are you sure it will resolve to a wchar_t? 

TCHAR @ compile time will be replaced with wchar_t or char according to the project settings.

Comment: Mahmoud, debug shows strDstFile is char[2048], though when I click "go to definition" on TCHAR, it shows "typedef wchar_t     TCHAR;"

Comment: @paulsm4 I tried that- it didn't matter. thanks.

Comment: Mahmoud, I think this might be the problem. I defined unicode in across the solution, but "TCHAR strDstFile[2048]; " compiles to char.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be several different influences on how TCHAR and the various TCHAR macros are expanded out see [_UNICODE vs UNICODE](http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2002-January/003565.html) and this posting [posting on _UNICODE vs UNICODE](http://forums.codeguru.com/archive/index.php/t-221286.html).

In your use of `mbstowcs()` the max size argument should specify the size of the destination buffer in characters and not the size of the source buffer.  This will help to prevent buffer overruns.  See [mbstowcs description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  also note that `mbstowcs()` will not zero terminate if the character count makes the max, a behavior similar to most of the character manipulation functions.

Since `mbstowcs()` is for wide character strings, you really should use wide character strings rather than TCHAR.

It does look like your problem is due to stack overwrite.  Are you using the same test data or different data and getting different results?

The various TCHAR and _T() extensions introduced by Microsoft for Visual Studio were really designed for allowing easy porting of applications between non-UNICODE versions of Windows such as Windows 95/98 and UNICODE versions of Windows such as Windows XP.  The multibyte string functionality was also designed to provide support for languages such as Thai or Simplified Chinese for Windows 95/98 since they did not have much core Windows API support for UNICODE which was part of the 32 bit Windows versions such as Windows XP or Windows CE.

In the UNICODE world of Windows XP and later, there seems to be very little value in using the TCHAR extensions since they just add a bit more complexity to source and compiler settings.

Not sure why you are using multi-byte strings rather than UNICODE.  I have an old application that targeted both Windows 98 and Windows XP and it does do some conversion at the user interface however everything is stored as wide character, UNICODE strings internally.  I introduced the original support for multibyte strings into the application as at the time it seemed necessary however though it seemed a good idea at the time, it introduced complexity that I really wish I had not done.  It may be that you are doing something similar.